# Create Temporary Table Where CONCAT GROUPS are placed into their own columns?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, one-to-many, temp-tables

I'm a bit of a MYsql newbie and I'm stumped as to how to do this.  I think I have to insert my results into a TEMPORARY TABLE, but I'm not sure.

I’d like to output a report from my database that shows each music album I have in my collection (album1, album2, album3) with a separate column for each format the album is available in (WAV, CD, cassette, etc).  I'm not sure how to take the many-to-one relationship between format_types and album and output a report where each format has a column and each album has only one row.

I have three tables (albums, format_types, and occurrences)

```
albums 
id      uuid
1       d2ec45e9-5fcc
2       949ebf32-8c95
3       98c7cc7e-ebe4
```

```
format_types
id  name
1   cassette
2   CD
3   DAT
4   WAV
```

```
album_occurrences
id  album_id format_type_id
1   1        1
2   2        2
3   3        3
4   2        3
5   3        1
6   1        2
7   1        3
8   1        4
9   2        4
```

The result I’d like is:

```
albums_by_format
album_id    format_name_1   format_name_2   format_name_3   format_name_4
1           Cassette        CD              DAT             WAV
2           NULL            CD              NULL            WAV
3           Cassette        NULL            DAT             NULL
```

I'm wondering the best method to return a result like the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should give you what you need. I say "should" because I haven't tested it.

```
SELECT `al`.`id`,
    (
    SELECT `ft`.`name`
    FROM `format_types` `ft`
    INNER JOIN `album_occurrences` `ao` ON `ft`.`id` = `ao`.`format_type_id`
    WHERE `ao`.`album_id` = `al`.`id`
    AND `ft`.`id` = 1
    ) `format_name_1`,
    (
    SELECT `ft`.`name`
    FROM `format_types` `ft`
    INNER JOIN `album_occurrences` `ao` ON `ft`.`id` = `ao`.`format_type_id`
    WHERE `ao`.`album_id` = `al`.`id`
    AND `ft`.`id` = 2
    ) `format_name_2`,
    (
    SELECT `ft`.`name`
    FROM `format_types` `ft`
    INNER JOIN `album_occurrences` `ao` ON `ft`.`id` = `ao`.`format_type_id`
    WHERE `ao`.`album_id` = `al`.`id`
    AND `ft`.`id` = 3
    ) `format_name_3`,
    (
    SELECT `ft`.`name`
    FROM `format_types` `ft`
    INNER JOIN `album_occurrences` `ao` ON `ft`.`id` = `ao`.`format_type_id`
    WHERE `ao`.`album_id` = `al`.`id`
    AND `ft`.`id` = 4
    ) `format_name_4`
FROM
`albums` `al`;
```

Let me know if it works :-)

Comment: That looks to me like it should work, you may want to create a view of it if you're wanting something easy to query in a report.

Comment: Thanks all!  I'm getting an error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the data you are running the query on. I've tested the query on the data set that you had given in your request and the results couldn't be more perfect.

The error that you are getting might be because either `format_types` has more than 1 records with the same ID or `album_occurrences` has more than one record with the same mapping.

Can you please mention the data set you ran the query on?

Comment: Perhaps it is the latter issued you mentioned?  There exists many records in album_occurrence that share album_id and format_id

Comment: Right, so I think the data isn't correct because `album_occurrences` should not have more than 1 record with the same `album_id` and `format_id`.

But now since there are, the solution is that you add a DISTINCT to all the subqueries, like `SELECT DISTINCT \`ft\`.\`name\`...`

Comment: Ah OK I understand.  I think I made my sample data set too simple.  The actual data set I'm working with is much more complex (for example, associated with each occurrence is a format_generation with terms like 'original', 'duplicate', 'master', etc.)  Thanks I think I understand now!! This has been a big help - subqueries look like the way to go.